# event grid not sending events for mounted NFS storage connection

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, nfs, azure-eventgrid

NFS support is available for blob storage accounts: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support)

I tried both Linux and Windows.

For Windows, I used this strategy for mounting a blob storage container with Windows [Using NFS with Azure Blob Storage](https://www.atmosera.com/blog/using-nfs-with-azure-blob-storage/). I wanted to use this strategy to lift-and-shift a client to the cloud and run our application as a service. All they need is the ability to create files in a directory and I was hoping to hook in to the BlobCreated event.

However, I found that Event Grid Subscriptions do not work if you created the file through the mounted drive (like notepad or copying a file there or emitting output into a file there). Yet creating a file through other means (API, azure storage explorer, etc), does fire event grid events.

Has anyone found a way to make these events fire for a mounted NFS blob storage drive?

Similarly, for linux, I ran the following on an Ubuntu image but it does not fire an event grid event.

```
    > sudo apt install nfs-common
    > sudo mount -o sec=sys,vers=3,nolock,proto=tcp 
[mystorageaccount].blob.core.windows.net:/[mystorageaccount]/[mycontainer]  /nfsdata
    > sudo echo 'content' > /nfsdata/something1.txt
    > ls /nfsdata
    something1.txt
```

Creating this file worked and I verified the file existed in the storage account. However, the event grid event was not fired :(

Other things I found:

- powershell does not see the drive. cannot pushd/cd into the drive.
- slowness: e.g. notepad will time out for a while if you try to create a notepad in that directory, after 30 seconds, it will work.
- Linux, however, was much faster than Windows to create the file.